# ngRoute RouteController getting called only once

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

<strike>I've a fiddler to show my setup.</strike>

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/dt6kkyy3</strike>

The problem is the routeController function is getting called only once on the page load, but then on hash change (as a result of link click), the function `routeController` is not getting called again.

I've my links generated in another ng module, not sure if the links have to be with in the same module as the router.

```
<div id="router">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<div id="navigation" data-ng-cloak>
        <ul id="folios" data-ng-controller="FoliosController" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li data-ng-repeat="folio in folios" ng-class="{active: isActive('/search/{{folio.productId}}')}">
                <a href="#/search/{{folio.productId}}">{{folio.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
```

**Edit:**

Problem has been further diagnosed. Any list/anchor that was generated by an ng controller, is not responding to hash changes outside the scope, while the static links are. from the plunkr link, "foo" and "bar" clicks trigger the controller but "abc" and "def" are not. please review. Question is how to make "abc" and "def" (dynamic links) respond to changes as well.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ea1OHa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The code is behaving as intended with the way you have it coded.  You are calling `routeController` in the constructor of the controller, but its not being invoked anywhere else (the router isn't going to do that either).

If you need the `routeController` function to be invoked on every route change consider binding to route changing events:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Take a look at this plunk.  Note I am binding to stateChangeSuccess instead since you are using the ui-router instead of ngRoute.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CiYLqnqAzrXoouMSXkuk

Comment: Thanks @sma for the reply, I'm relatively new to angular, can you please help with some demonstration in my code. I assumed that ngRoute is watching my url all the time and will call routeController on hash change

Comment: I believe it's _already_ **bound** to route change in the config, inside `when` function call

Comment: Added plunk to my answer

Comment: If you are using ngRoute, then you can use $routeChangeSuccess instead

Comment: based on what I've learned, I've updated my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/dt6kkyy3/6/ but still no success, kindly review

Comment: Your fiddle is incomplete.  I can't really debug what's going on without all the code there.  For instance, I can't trigger a route change to see why its not working.  Can you fork the plunk I created and put all your code in that instead?

Comment: here you go, a basic setup, http://plnkr.co/edit/WYtnRRMXiwyb6Wi1ANZl?p=preview please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62693/discussion-between-sma-and-user2727195).

Comment: bro, I figured out what the problem is, would need a bit of more of your help please, in my example the anchors are static, while in reality I have another ng-controller populating them, and any clicks there are not intercepted else where, I did a test with some static links and it does work, updated plunkr in a bit

Comment: Here's a new plunkr, foo, bar are being called because they are static, abc, def are not responded as they were generated by mg-controller http://plnkr.co/edit/WYtnRRMXiwyb6Wi1ANZl?p=preview